# logic for python web scraper for business names

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am new to python and was wondering if there was a way to get the business name of a website through a python script.

I have 1000s of businesses I need to validate for their names and was wondering if it was possible to scale this up by looking at their website or address and find the registered business name under the address.

I want to ask this question here before I waste my research time on if this is even possible.

Thank you for any help in advanced.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Otherwise, this is too broad.

Comment: Do they have some type of generic layout?

Comment: so lets say I was given a bunch of websites urls or addresses. I want to use python to help me determine what the business name for this website is or through the address find out the business name.

Comment: Import into CSV so in column 1 I will have website url and column two I will out output of my python script which will be the business name.

Comment: It honestly depends on the website and what content it has. To say that every website with have their organization neatly printed would be irresponsible. You'll probably want to do a domain whois and (assuming their information is listed) scrape that.

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, the page title of the website homepage could be an approximation of the full business name.

The following is a very simple example of pinging a website homepage and returning the `<title>` tag, an approximation of the business name.  You need to install the requests and lxml libraries.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()

urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://facebook.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text
    tree  = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser) 
    title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
    print url, title

>>>
http://google.com ['Google']
http://facebook.com ['Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More']
http://stackoverflow.com ['Stack Overflow']
```

In other cases, you might want to navigate to a 'Legal' or 'Contact Us' page if you need find the full legal business name.  That's much trickier because the name isn't necessarily associated with any html tag; it's likely just free text floating somewhere on your page.

Comment: Thank you for the code! Is there a way to find out the registered business name through a state business website. Isnt it by law that a business must register their business name through the state for tax purposes? Or if I have the business address how can I find the business name.

Comment: Asking this because I know it can get tricky if I were to crawl multiple sites with different HTML structures.

Comment: These are different questions beyond the scope of StackOverflow but what you can start googling is "[state] corporate registry," e.g. https://delecorp.delaware.gov/tin/controller, http://www.dos.ny.gov/corps/bus_entity_search.html

Comment: Thank you for all the help. As I said I am a beginner in python. Is there any web scraping scripts that I can look at to help me better understand the scope of my question and what alternative sources I can use to help me determine if this is scalable?

Comment: There are many tutorials out there for scraping, just need to search around.